# How to send the selected value of jQuery select after I have disabled it?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery select option where I have to kind of freeze (disable) from any changes. But when I do

```
 $(this).attr('disable', true);
```

the select freezes but the value it sends in null as there is no more anything selected in it. How can I freeze and still send the selected values?

Comment: You can add a hidden field with the same name and value.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Just make sure to use array name, e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="values[]" value="..."/>` if you are setting multiple inputs with the same name.

Comment: but after you freeze it, the value is lost. The issue is how can I retain the values?

Comment: Set a hidden input in your form and a function `.onchange(...)` to change the value of that input with the value of your select

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value

Comment: Just a suggestion: _As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the `.attr()` method._

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the `disabled` input fields to post. Use `readonly` or `hidden` fields or make this `select` style to `display:none`.

Best will be use `readonly`

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the element again before submit.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {

  $(this).find(':input:disabled') // Find disabled form elements within the form
    .prop('disabled', false); // Enable elements

});
```