# Is it possible to disable a select statement but post the PHP statements?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-select

I have an option select form but when I disable the select tag it won't post the PHP statement.

```
<select disabled name="project" data-placeholder="Project..." class="chzn-select" style="width:300px;"tabindex="4">
    <option value='<?=$overzicht[0]->idProject;?>' ><?=$overzicht[0]->Titel;?></option> 
</select>
```

When I leave the "disabled" tag it will post. But when I try with the disable tag it won't post.

Comment: if you want to sent the data to server why dont you make it `readonly`

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value

Comment: You can send it as a hidden variable..

Answer (score 2):

Try `readonly` instead of `disabled`.