# How to send the disabled element value to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the next checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="permanentEmployee" checked="" id="permanentEmployee" disabled="">
```

I've set the attribute `disabled` to true and submitted the form

```
$("#permanentEmployee").prop('disabled', true);`
```

On server side, if I do:

```
request.getParameter("permanentEmployee")
```

I get the value as *Null*, though I get the the correct value (i.e *True*) if I don't disable the checkbox. Why am I not getting the disabled checkbox value as *True* even if it is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled form elements are not sent via form submit. <strike>You can consider using read-only instead</strike>

One idea would be

```
$('#permanentEmployee').click(function(){
        return false; // even if the user clicks on it it will not change
});

$('#permanentEmployee').prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/M3LfA/1/

Comment: Would this still be the case if you disabled via CSS?

Comment: @user3759531 how would you disabled it via CSS?

Comment: Apologies i thought you could do this with css

Comment: The "readonly" attribute isn't valid for checkboxes... only for text-type fields, text, email, number, etc.

Comment: But i did not find anything in jquery or javascript to make checkbox readonly instead of disabled. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @user3198603 Sorry, was meaning the readonly attribute but as BobBrown pointed out with will not work with a checkbox. Instead you could try a workaround

Answer (score 1):

Just before submitting the form (onsubmit listener) you could enable the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled check boxes (and probably other form elements) are not sent to the server.

There are a couple of solutions here: [How to ensure a <select> form field is submitted when it is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value)