# How to disable select tag in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I want to disable my select option because is auto fill.
So the problem is that when I use `readonly="readonly"` and `disable="disable"` it changes into a disabled field but it sends `null` as value due to that my address is not updating. It's MVC template code, using backbone.js.

```
    <div class="login-register" data-validation="control">
      <select name="state123" id="state123" class="sumary state" disabled > 
        {{#each states}}
          <option value="{{code}}" {{#if selected}}selected{{/if}}>
            {{name}}
          </option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
    </div>
<input type="hidden" name="state" id="state" class="cart-summary-estimate-input state" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it send the null value...._ when does it happen? What the behavior you expect?

Comment: basically it's part of address form so its mean due to null value of state address is not updating on the server.

Comment: So what the expected bahavior, what should it do instead?

Comment: Expected behavior is that it should update address on server. It's required field so if state is null then address will not update.

Comment: The `disable` option is what is making that parameter not being sended. Use only the `readonly` option and it should be sended

Comment: both are not working.

Comment: I see (`readonly` is not available for `select`)... Then i guess the hidden field is the way to go... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/how-to-ensure-a-select-form-field-is-submitted-when-it-is-disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ensure a <select> form field is submitted when it is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/how-to-ensure-a-select-form-field-is-submitted-when-it-is-disabled)

Comment: I have tried select with hidden input tag but it's not working. @A. Iglesias

Comment: Edit the question and show your html with the hidden field option, to see where's the error

Comment: Now check it..@A. Iglesias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the value of hidden input. It should be

```
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="{{code}}"/>
```

Comment: @salmankhan you should set whatever value you want to submit as the value of state. It's an example