# Undefined Index While fetching values from HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having an undefined index error While Executing the following code.

I have fetched data on run time in form from database table tbl_usr_training_master, i want to add this table fields into another table with the name tbl_usr_training_master2. Also i am getting first table ID on runtime using $_GET method from another page. The following code is not working as per i desire, your help is much more appericiated

Following is the PHP Code, i have tried both methods, 1. INSERT INTO and 2. UPDATE Table.

```
$eid = $_GET['rid'];
$query = "Select * from tbl_usr_training_master where trai_master_id = '$eid';";

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);

$trainingID  = $row['trai_master_id']; //Tbl_usr_training_master PRIMARY KEY ID
$TrainerName = $row['trai_name'];
$TrainerExp = $row['trai_expertise'];
$TrainingTitle = $row ['tari_program_title'];
$TrainingDate = $row['trai_date'];
$TrainingDays = $row['t_days'];
$TrainingVenue = $row['Venue'];
$TrainingCity = $row['City'];
$TrainingPartOrg = $row ['trai_partner_organization'];
$TrainingCat = $row['trai_type_cata'];
$TrainingSubCat = $row['trai_type_subcata'];


if(isset($_POST['ButtonPost']))
{
    //$TrainerName="";
    $trainingID  = $_POST['id']; //Tbl_usr_training_master PRIMARY KEY ID
    $Trainer_Name = $_POST['trainer_name'];
    $TrainerExp = $_POST['TrainerExp'];
    $TrainingTitle = $_POST['Trainingtitle'];
    $TrainingDate = $_POST['TrainingDate'];
    $TrainingDays = $_POST['TrainingDays'];
    $TrainingVenue = $_POST['Venue'];
    $TrainingCity = $_POST['City'];
    $TrainingPartOrg = $_POST['PartnerOrg'];
    $TrainingCat = $_POST['TrainingCat'];
    $TrainingSubCat = $_POST['traningsubcat'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_usr_training_master2 
(trai_master_id, trai_name,trai_expertise,tari_program_title,trai_date,t_days,Venue,City,trai_partner_organization,trai_type_cata, trai_type_subcata)
VALUES
('$trainingID','$TrainerName','$TrainerExp','$TrainingTitle','$TrainingDate','$TrainingDays','$TrainingVenue','$TrainingCity',
'$TrainingPartOrg','$TrainingCat','$TrainingSubCat');";


   /* $query = "UPDATE tbl_usr_training_master2 SET
        trai_master_id = '$trainingID',
        trai_name = '$Trainer_Name',
        trai_expertise = '$TrainerExp',
        tari_program_title = '$TrainingTitle',
        trai_date = '$TrainingDate',
        t_days = '$TrainingDays',
        trai_date = '$TrainingDate',
        Venue = '$TrainingVenue',
        City = '$TrainingCity',
        trai_partner_organization = '$TrainingPartOrg',
        trai_type_cata = '$TrainingCat',
        trai_type_subcata = '$TrainingSubCat'
        WHERE trai_master_id='$trainingID'"; */

    $rs = mysqli_query($con, $query);

}
$result = mysqli_multi_query($con, $query);
if ($result != 1)
{
    //die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);

}
```

My HTML Code i want to get values and INSERT into table

```
 <form role="form" name="frmreg" id="frmreg" action="" method="post" onclick="validate();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div align="center">
  <table class="table table-bordered" width="108%" height="162" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" scope="row" bgcolor="#999999"><div align="center">Post Event Budget Form  <br />
        </div></th>
      </tr>


      <tr>
          <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Pre Budget Event Form ID</th>
          <th colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" style="font-size:10px" scope="row">
              <input type="text" required="required" Value="<?php echo $trainingID;?>" name="id" id="id" disabled>
          </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th width="74" scope="row"  style="font-size:10px" align="left">Training Program / Event Title</th>
      <th colspan="3" scope="row" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" align="left">
        <input type="text" required="required" Value="<?php echo $TrainingTitle;?>" placeholder='"TOPIC"' name="Trainingtitle" id="Trainingtitle" width="auto" disabled/>
        </th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Trainer Experties</th>
      <th colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" style="font-size:10px" scope="row">
        <select name="TrainerExp" class="form-control" required="required" required = "required" id="TrainerExp" disabled >
        <option selected ><?php echo $TrainerExp;?></option>
        <option value="Yes">Export</option>
            <option value="Yes">MBA Marketing</option>
            <option value="Yes">Phd Computer Sciences</option>
        </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Trainer Name</th>
      <th colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" style="font-size:10px" scope="row">
        <select name="trainer_name" class="form-control" required = "required" id="trainer_name" disabled >
        <option selected value="<?php echo $TrainerName;?>"> <?php echo $TrainerName;?></option>
        <option value="Yes">Ali</option>
        <option value="No">Aslam</option>
        <option value="No">Iqbal</option>


        </select>
        </th>
      </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Date of the Event</th>
      <th width="179" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" scope="row">
        <input type="date" required="required" Value="<?php echo $TrainingDate;?>" name="TrainingDate" id="TrainingDate" disabled /></th>
      <th width="327" scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="center">Event Duration (Days)</th>
      <th width="457" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" scope="row">
        <input type="number" required="required" Value="<?php echo $TrainingDays;?>" name="TrainingDays" id="TrainingDays" disabled/>
        </th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Training Categoery</th>
      <th colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" style="font-size:10px" scope="row">
        <select name="TrainingCat" class="form-control" Value="<?php echo $TrainingCat;?>" required = "required" id="TrainingCat" disabled >
            <option selected disabled>Post Budget Form</option>
        </select>
        </th>
      </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Training Subcatagoery</th>
      <th colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" style="font-size:10px" scope="row">
        <select name="traningsubcat" class="form-control" required = "required" id="traningsubcat"  >
        <option selected value="<?php echo $TrainingSubCat;?>" disabled><?php echo $TrainingSubCat;?></option>
        <!--<option disabled>Select Options</option>
        <option value="No" disabled>In House Training </option>
        <option value="No" disabled>YEP</option>
        <option value="No" disabled>T-Desk Inhouse</option>
        <option value="No" disabled>T-Desk Outsource</option>
        <option value="No" disabled>T-Desk Online</option> -->
        </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Venue</th>
          <th width="179" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" scope="row">
              <input type="text" Value="<?php echo $TrainingVenue;?>" required="required" name="Venue" id="Venue" disabled /></th>
          <th width="327" scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="center">City</th>
          <th width="457" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" scope="row">
              <input type="text" required="required" Value="<?php echo $TrainingCity;?>" name="City" id="City" disabled />
          </th>
      <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="font-size:10px" align="left">Partner Organization (If any) </th>
      <th colspan="3" bgcolor="#B8D8D8" scope="row" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="PartnerOrg" Value="<?php echo $TrainingPartOrg;?>" id="PartnerOrg" disabled/>
        </th>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered" width="1065" height="771" border="1" align="center">
  </div>
  <tr>
```

From Where i am getting ID:

```
$query = "select * from tbl_usr_training_master";
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$html ="";
$i=1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
$html .='<tr>
    <td>'.$row['trai_master_id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['trai_name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['trai_expertise'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['tari_program_title'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['trai_date'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['Venue'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['City'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['trai_type_cata'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['trai_type_subcata'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['t_days'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['trai_status'].'</td>' . '
    <td>
                            <a href="#" class="view" title="View" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE417;</i></a>
                            <a href="post_form.php?rid='.$row['trai_master_id'].'" class="edit" title="Close Pre Budget Form" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
</tr>';
$i=1;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: i have tried it too, but still i am getting no where,

Comment: The same code is working for another table, but that was only one table, it is getting values from run time while editing the existing values against the specific ID. i have tried it with the same method, for this one, it is not working.

Comment: @MahmoodUlHassan Do not use `SELECT *`, instead specify the columns you want to read.

Comment: Actually i want to read all of the columns, as i need all the data to show in form and put into another database table

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled):

> The Boolean `disabled` attribute, when present, makes the element not
>   mutable, focusable, or even submitted with the form.

None of the input fields that are disabled will be in the `$_POST` array, and program will give undefined index. Most of the elements are disabled.

One common solution is to use "hidden" input elements, as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/how-to-ensure-a-select-form-field-is-submitted-when-it-is-disabled).