# How to make disabled/readonly functionality for radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know we can't make ***readonly*** radio button and checkbox. I tried to disable  radio button and checkbox but in IE it is not visible.

Is any alternative way to do the same like ***disabled*** / ***readonly*** using jQuery, CSS, JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, but it does exactly the same as what you've already tried, sets the disabled property to disabled etc.

Comment: what code you are doing for that..

Comment: Check the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953017/why-cant-radio-buttons-be-readonly
It does an excellent job making radio buttons effectively readonly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the following code to avoid clicks on elements you don't want user to change

```
$(':radio,:checkbox').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

You can use proper selector to limit the clicks.

Comment: thanks it works. Is it possible to apply background color to radiobuttton and checkbox, so that it looks like disabled without using image? I tried using     $(':radio,:checkbox').css("background-color", 'red");

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  You have to use some sort of image for that purpose. But if you want to give it a disabled effect its better to disable it;  then it will look consistent on all browsers.  I thought u want to disable a checkbox/radio button without the disable effect.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want disable like functionality without disable effect. If I specified disabled to checkbox and radio button it is not clearly visiable in IE.

Comment: This has an unfortunate side effect in IE (tested 9/10/11): if you click on non-checked button, the checked one gets visually "de-checked".

Answer (score 8):

Yon can write like this:-

in your script:

```
 jQuery('#radio').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

or you can add class according to you..

if it will not compatible with IE give compatibility also..

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

then check..

you can also try this:

```
jQuery("#youridname input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
```

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone who is tempted to use this solution, keep in mind that disabled elements will not be posted when a form is submitted.

Answer (score 4):

```
selectedRow
    .find('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)')
    .each(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

selected row is just the HTML element below which I want to locate the radio buttons I am interested.
the whole script is only called once a radio button has been selected.
when executed, it locates the unselected radio buttons and disables them.

hence, giving me the desired result of disabling the non-selected radio buttons, while maintaining the selected option.

this result seemed to be a better option, then
1. laying an image over the radio button, to avoid the user from selected another option.
2. `.click(function(){ return false; })`, which just hides the selection when the unselected option is selected
3. disabling all the radio buttons, where the selection is lost.

hope this helps you,
cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If radio button is already checked and if you click on checked radio button it change value from true to false. For  this scenario following code works

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type = "radio"]').change(function () {
        this.checked = false;
    });
});
```