# Changing the value of radio button at run time

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="rdo" id="rdo_1" checked="checked" />Yes
<input type="radio" value="0" name="rdo" id="rdo_0" />No
```

And on some `DropDown` index change I try to set the `rdo_1` to Yes. 
And make them both disabled.

But for some reason it is not setitng the radio button to True for first one.

What Am I Doing Wrong?

Here is How I did it:

```
$("input:radio[name='rdo']:checked").val('1');
$("input:radio[id='rdo_1']:checked").val('1');
$('#rdo_1').attr('disabled', true);
$('#rdo_0').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: If you mention a drop down, it would be good to include that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** *You have disabled the radio buttons so that they can only be set via drop-down, etc; however, this causes problems because only enabled elements are submitted with the form. Here is a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583392/how-to-make-disabled-readonly-like-functionality-to-radio-button-and-checked-box) that gives a dirty work around. It will take the input from radio buttons and do nothing with them. I've added it to my fiddle.*

`$(':radio').click(function(){
    return false;
});`

Here is how to do it with a drop down box. You need to change the radio button to use `prop` (property) instead of `val`.

```js
$("#dropdown").on("change", function() {
  //Get the value of the dropdown box
  var dropDownVal = $(this).val();
  
  if (dropDownVal == 0) {
    //If the first drop down option was selcted
    $("#rdo_1").prop("checked", true);
    
  } else if (dropDownVal == 1) {
     //If the second drop down option was selcted
    $("#rdo_0").prop("checked", true);
  } else{
    //If the third drop down option was selcted
    $("#rdo_1").prop("checked", false);
    $("#rdo_0").prop("checked", false);
  }

});

//Disable the radio buttons - crude
$(':radio').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dropdown'>
  <option value="0">YES</option>
  <option value="1">NO</option>
  <option value="2">CLEAR</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" value="1" name="rdo" id="rdo_1" checked='checked' />Yes
<input type="radio" value="0" name="rdo" id="rdo_0" />No
```

Comment: No need for an if statement...  `prop("checked", $(this).val() == 0)`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm not sure I follow. My code was an example off how to use the values from a drop-down to set the value of radio button. What do the above comment do?

Comment: You have duplicate code because you have an if statement. If you place the if logic directly into the prop method, it reduces code.  **OH wait nevermind**.

Comment: so I don't need 'rdo'   that was the name of both of radio buttons at all ?  and this will SAVE  correctly when form submits  ?

Comment: Well in my own testing before posting the question I had tried$('#rdo1').prop('checked', true);   too .. it DOES select it . but does NOT SAVE when form posts.

Comment: @Travolta Oh, wait, you are disabling the radio buttons. Disabled HTML elements will not be submitted with the form

Comment: @blackandorangecat  yes requirements need me to disable them too. . So what to do now?

Comment: @Travolta Look at my edit above. Radio buttons do not support the `readonly` property - you will have to tweak your html or your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, for readonly part I will probably use this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953017/why-cant-radio-buttons-be-readonly

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery's Prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="rdo" id="rdo_1" checked="checked" />Yes
<input type="radio" value="0" name="rdo" id="rdo_0" />No
</br>
</br>
<input type="button" data-target="#rdo_1" value="Yes"/>
<input type="button" data-target="#rdo_0" value="No"/>
```

> What's wrong with my own code?

None of the code you have presented is modifying the `checked` attribute.

```
.val('1')
```

Changes the `value=""` attribute.

> Also what is .data('target')

[jQuery's .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) gets the value of `data-` attributes.

with

```
data-blah="asdf";
```

therefore

```
.data('blah') == "asdf";
```

Comment: Also what is .data('target')

Comment: None of your code is modifying the *checked* attribute?

Comment: @Travolta Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-* to read more about `data` attributes

Comment: @blackandorangecat your link is 404 my friend.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Whups. Looks like it cut off the asterisk at the end. `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*`