# jQuery Dynamic form input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, input

This question is based off of another StackOverflow question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37618826/5076162).

My goal is to build simple validation that ensures input fields are filled in sequential order based on their index (natural flow).

» The main complexity is that I'm trying to consolidate validation across different types of input.

» Specifically, radio button groups should be validated as one entity.  When using the `.prev()` and `.next()` methods, the gender radio group should move to essay or age respectively, not male or female.

» The next bug is that I cannot get the age row to properly disable if the content in any previous row is undone/removed.  It does not work consistently and I cannot figure out why.

» The validate button should make items that are filled in green, otherwise highlight them in red color.

If there is a more refined approach to this please feel free to elaborate.  If there are easier selectors that I could be utilizes to build up the arrays for more streamlined manipulation and validation, please also enlighten me and share.

[Almost Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ftrLetxa/8/)

```js
//StackOverflow Question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/37618826/5076162 [06-03-2016]

//Step 1: Declare the collection of all inputs that should be manipulated.
var $inputFields = $('textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="radio"]');

//Step 2: Insert the collection into a single array using the .push() method.
var arr = [];

$inputFields.each(function() {
  arr.push($(this));
});

//Step 3: Iterate through the newly created array and perform certain functions.
//Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437904/5076162
$.each(arr, function(i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    $(this).attr('readonly', 'readonly').addClass('disabled');
    $(':radio[readonly]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
    //console.log("Iteration number: " + i);
  }
});

var $justRadio = $('input[type="radio"]:disabled');

//Step 4: Detect input and apply logic for each situation.  Note that different input types require different syntax.
$inputFields.on("propertychange input change focus blur", function(i) {
  var index = $inputFields.index(this);
  var next = $inputFields.eq(index + 1);
  var $checkedRadio = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').length;
  var radioCounter = $justRadio.length;

  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $inputFields.filter(function() {
      return $inputFields.index(this) > index;
    }).attr("readonly", true).attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
    //console.log('disable Fired');
  } else {
    next.attr("readonly", false).attr('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
    $justRadio = $('input[type="radio"]:disabled');
    //console.log(radioCounter);
    if (radioCounter < 2) {
      $justRadio.closest('tr').find($justRadio).attr("readonly", false).attr('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
    }
  }
  if ($checkedRadio > 0 && $justRadio.length === 0) {
    $inputFields.last().attr("readonly", false).attr('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
    //console.log("This fired: lastRow");
  }

  //Step 5: Implement a user interface button so they know they have filled in all fields.
  var emptyCount = 0;
  $inputFields.not($('input[type="radio"]')).each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
      emptyCount = +1;
    }
    //console.log("Empty Count: " + emptyCount);
  });

  var vRCount = 0;
  $inputFields.not($('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], textarea')).each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      vRCount = +1;
    }
    //console.log("Empty Count: " + emptyCount);
  });

  $('input.validateCheck').on("click", function() {
    if (emptyCount === 0 && vRCount > 0) {
      $inputFields.closest('tr').find('td').css("color", "green");
      $('input.validateCheck').text("Success!").attr("value", "Success!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: arial;
}
input {
  width: 450px;
  text-align: center;
}
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  width: 448px;
  text-align: left;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  width: 15px;
}
div.gender {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: none;
  width: 219px;
}
.disabled {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
input[type="button"] {
  width: 546px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Essay:</td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="4" cols=""></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender:</td>
      <td>
        <div class='gender'>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</div>
        <div class='gender'>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="age" min="18" max="99">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input class='validateCheck' type="button" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you want tabindex attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 form validations.  It is a lot easier and faster. Hope this helps...

```
    <style>

    form{font-size:100%;min-width:560px;max-width:620px;width:590px;margin:0 auto;padding:0}
    form fieldset{clear:both;font-size:100%;border-color:#000;border-style:solid none none;border-width:1px 0 0;margin:0;padding:10px}
    form fieldset legend{font-size:150%;font-weight:400;color:#000;margin:0;padding:0 5px}
    label{font-size:100%}
    label u{font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline}
    input,select,textarea{font-family:Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:100%;color:#000}

    input:required ,select:required, textarea:required, radio:required{
        font-family:Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:100%;
        color:#000; 
        border-color:red;
        background: #fff url(images/red-asterisk.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    }

    input:focus ,select:focus, textarea:focus, radio:focus{
        background: #fff url(invalid.png) no-repeat 98% center;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
        border-color: #b03535
    }

    input:valid ,select:valid, textarea:valid, radio:valid{
        background: #fff url(valid.png) no-repeat 98% center;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
        border-color: #28921f;

    }


    :valid {box-shadow:  0 0 5px green}
    :-moz-submit-invalid {box-shadow:  0 0 5px pink}



</style>

        <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>First name:</td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last name:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Essay:</td>
          <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="20" required></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gender:</td>
          <td>
            <div class='gender'>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required> Male</div>
            <div class='gender'>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required> Female</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Age:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="age" min="18" max="99" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input class='validateCheck' type="submit" value="Validate" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Definitely a useful post though not the answer I was looking for.  It led me to look into HTML5 form validation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation