# How to block User from changing DropDownList value using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I have a dropdownlist, I am selecting its valus from server side code. I don't want to allow user to change it. Means He must not be able to change it neither by mouse click and not by keyboard. I want to handle it from Client Side. 
Please suggest only javascript methods.

Comment: Just disable the dropdown from client side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make html <select> element look like "disabled", but pass values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769664/how-to-make-html-select-element-look-like-disabled-but-pass-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try it:**

**Jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dropdounid").prop("disabled", true);
 });
```

**OR**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dropdounid").attr("disabled", true);
 });
```

**OR**

**Javascript**

you can disable `Asp.net DropDownList` using below code in javascript at client side.

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtActualWindSpeed.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
```

**Edit**

you can put this code inside of `head tag or body tag`.

```
<head>
  <script>
     document.getElementById('<%=txtActualWindSpeed.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
  </script>
</head>
```

I hope it will helpful to you.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tft4t/386/)

Comment: for which client side event I should write this piece of code. This is big concern for me.

Comment: if you don't want to allow user to change `dropdown` then you can keep this code in your source code `<head><script>here put above code</script></head>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(selector).attr('disabled',true);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNG7V/)