# mark a spring checkbox as readOnly

Tags: spring-mvc

How can I mark a Spring Checkbox as readOnly instead of disabled? I want to do it using a simple attribute like readonly = "true" but this does not work. I am hoping to avoid writing a javascript just for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.checkbox) the option which should do the trick is: `disabled`.

Comment: please leave a comment while downcasting. I might be wrong and I would like to learn from it.

Comment: Sorry about that. In the question, I mentioned that I do not want to mark it as disabled.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I didn't notice that fact, since as far as I know, there is no such state as `read only` for checkboxes in HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly You could try playing around with JavaScript and force a quick check: `if (state_changes) checkbox.setPrevState()`. This is an ugly hack, but could work.