# Razor how to create a CheckBox and make it READONLY?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using MVC 3 and Razor

At the moment I'm using

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel

    @foreach (var item in Model.MyProperty)
{  
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.AdvSlotId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.AdvSlotId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.AdvSlotId })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.AdvSlotId
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Description
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.CheckBox(item.IsPublished, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Notes
        </td>
    </tr>    
}
```

The VIEW MODEL:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public MyViewModel(List<AdvSlot> advSlots)
        {
            MyProperty= advSlots;
        }

        public List<AdvSlot> MyProperty { get; set; }

    }
}
```

To display a Check Box for a property in my Model. As I'm doing is wrong so I can only display a text like TRUE.

Could you please tell me how to create the CheckBox with Razor? I would also need have it as READONLY.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPublished, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

UPDATE:

Assuming that your class `AdvSlot` contains a property `IsPublished` you can write in your loop:

```
<td>
    @Html.CheckBox(item.AdvSlotId + "_IsPublished", item.IsPublished, new { @disabled = "disabled" });
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks LeftyX for your comment, I receive an error and I cannot create textcheckbox. could you please help me out? thanks

Comment: Please note MyProperty is a Property in the ViewModel any idea how to solve it? thanks

Comment: @GibboK: could you, please, include your viewmodel as well?

Comment: Included, please let em know if you need more information, once again thanks for your time

Comment: Thanks, now is working I have also find another solution: @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=> item.IsPublished, new {@disabled = "disabled"})

Comment: @GibboK: Have a look at your HTML. Your solution would generate duplicate IDs.

Comment: Thanks Lefty you are right, I'm now adopting your solution which create unique ID. Once again many thanks :)

Comment: Bad solution, disabled checkboxes are not passed back in the post.

Comment: @StuartDobson: Ok. Offer your solution then.

Comment: A few ideas here but nothing is clean.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Answer (score 36):

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { onclick = "return false" })
```

This should work. However i got a problem with @disabled = "disabled". If i make the checkbox checked by default and make the checkbox disabled at the same time it wont post with its value. At controller it will get false. Using "return false" user wont able to change the value and it will also post the value which has set on load as by default.

Comment: Your answer should be accepted. If we use property @disabled="disabled", the textboxfor always passes FALSE to server

Comment: @Ahn Hoang I agree with you. This is a perfect answer in my opinion as I have faced same thing you said earlier.

Comment: This is a better solution

Comment: @AnhHoang I believe the server actually just omits values for any disabled controls; it's the model binding on the server that initializes the property of the viewmodel to `false` (the default for boolean fields).

Answer (score 8):

I'm using MVC4, you get the same effect with a simple something like

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.IsPublished)
```

No need to care to select *checkbox* or set *disabled* yourself. Not sure, if this is a new feature in MVC4, so maybe it will work in MVC3 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I will just add my case which may be useful to someone.. if you have html attribute too in your checkboxFor then

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.item, new { onclick = "return false", Title = "is not editable",htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

@Anupam Roy answer will work good.just adding my case.Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your MyViewModel you can remove the setter :

```
public bool IsPublished 
{
   get {
        //... get from db
       }
}
```

and in your View :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPublished, new {@disabled="disabled"})
```

Comment: this line should give you error @Html.CheckBox(item.IsPublished, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) , it has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

In Razor:

```
<input asp-for="IsStoped" type="checkbox" name="IsStoped" value="@Model.IsStoped" disabled />
```