# checkbox readonly attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have Input checkbox element inside td tag of a table. When I try to set readonly attribute to checkbox , not working , still it  can be ticked or unticked even if I set `readonly` attribute to input checkbox.

```html
var isdisabled = true
var isDofDisabled = true

<td>
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="checkbox" 
        readonly="@(isdisabled || isDofDisabled ? " readonly" : null)" 
        asp-for="@Model.[i].IsDayOffMarked" />
    </span>
    <input type="number" 
      readonly="@(isdisabled || isDofDisabled ? "readonly" : null)" 
      placeholder="0.00" 
      style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" 
      class="form-control format-text" 
      asp-for="@Model.[i].DayOffHrs" />
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you tried? disabled="@(isdisabled || isDofDisabled ? "disabled" : null)"

Comment: @Alan Pauil:  See [Razor how to create a CheckBox and make it READONLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11308661/6630084)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input Checkbox cannot be set as `readonly`. You should set it as `disabled` instead since checkbox doesn't support `readonly`.