# How to detect .click() on disabled checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

js/jQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  // Does not fire if I click a <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
});
```

How do I make something happend in jQuery when someone clicks a disabled checkbox?

Comment: You can not click on a disabled checkbox.

Comment: If the checkbox is disabled, the click event doesn't get fired. Can you use `readonly` instead of `disabled`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input The answer in that post uses an element surrounding the input control as well as a secondary control which intercepts the click event which than can be used to trigger your actual click event. You still can do `$('input[type=checkbox]').click()` to trigger the click event programmatically even if the input is disabled.

Comment: @JoãoSilva: Using `readonly="true"` greys out the control but still lets the user check/uncheck it. In Chrome anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reading over the comment again regarding using `readonly` from `JoãoSilva`. You could use that and connect it with some logic in the click event.

Using `readonly` gives you the disabled look, just like `disabled` does but it still lets you click it.

Use readonly like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" readonly="readonly">​
```

Then in your script cancel the event if readonly is set.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var isReadOnly = $(this).attr("readonly") === undefined ? false : true;

    if (isReadOnly) {
        return false;
    }

    // other code never executed if readonly is true.
});
​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/ZqvmM/)

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. It provides the desired functionality, and is least hacky.

Comment: `readonly` should be specified with either no value or the value `readonly`, i.e. `readonly="readonly"`, not `true`.

Comment: @Barmar: I fixed that now and added a DEMO. Thank you.

Comment: Isnt readonly a property? If so, it could be simplified like:

if ($(this).prop('readonly')) return false;

Comment: @Lilleman: I used `attr` as I didn't know what version of jQuery you had. `prop` was added in 1.6 so, yes, you are correct if you are using at least 1.6 the relevant line can be changed to `var isReadOnly = !$(this).prop("readonly");` and code still works.

Comment: ? If I set readonly on a checkbox, it is still check-able. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Answer (score 10):

You will not be able to capture the click event reliably across all browsers. Your best bet is to place a transparent element above to capture the click.

HTML

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
</div>​
```

JavaScript

```
$(':checkbox:disabled').next().click(function(){
    var checkbox = $(this.prevNode);
    // Does fire now :)
});
```

Note: This is an idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input) which I improved on.

Comment: Its not exactly what I want, but this solves my problem, so I will accept it in a minute when I can. :)

Comment: @Lilleman If you want a cross browser solution it's the best you can do. Glad I could help.

Comment: @ianpgall the title of the OP is "How to trigger .click() on disabled checkbox"

Comment: @ianpgall This conversation doesn't help the community or the OP. Please stop trolling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't...but you can fake it by placing a div over the input with a transparent background, and define the click function on that div.

```
$('input').each(function(){
    if(true == ($(this).prop('disabled'))){
        var iTop = $(this).position().top;
        var iLeft = $(this).position().left;
        var iWidth = $(this).width();
        var iHeight = $(this).height();
    $('body').append('<div class="disabledClick" style="position:absolute;top:'+iTop+'px;left:'+iLeft+'px;width:'+iWidth+'px;height:'+iHeight+'px;background:transparent;"></div>');    
    }       
});

//delegate a click function for the 'disabledClick'.


$('body').on('click', '.disabledClick', function(){
   console.log('This is the click event for the disabled checkbox.');
});
```

[Here's the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCfet/)

Answer (score 0):

I see no other option as to add `<div>` block layer over the checkbox. So the solution should be the following:

```
function addDisabledClickHandler(el, handler) {
    $("<div />").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: el.position().top,
        left: el.position().left,
        width: el.width(),
        height: el.height()
    }).click(handler).appendTo("body");
}

var el = $("input[type='checkbox']");
addDisabledClickHandler(el, function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/q6u64/

Answer (score 0):

I actually do this quite often to stop people from changing checkboxes if those changes have already been committed to the database. However, if you want to change it or see a click at least.. then I just wrap the input in a label element and check the child input.

HTML :

```
<label class="checkbox-label">
    <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="declared" disabled checked>
</label>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.checkbox-label').on(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let checkBox = $(this).find('.input-checkbox');

    // if checkbox is disabled, do something

    if (checkBox.prop('disabled')) {
        // I usually put some enter password to confirm change... but I know you want to just show a click

        console.log('click')
    } else {
        // your checkbox should act as normal

        console.log('click')
    }
})
```

Hope this helps :)