# How to get the value of disabled check box in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC application and I am having a problem of getting the value of the check box when it is disabled.

**in report.jsp page :**

```
<form:checkbox type="checkbox" path="corporateColumn" id="corporateColumn" value="true" checked="checked" disabled="true" />
```

**in ReportForm.java :**

```
boolean corporateColumn ;

public boolean isCorporateColumn() {
        return corporateColumn;
}

public void setCorporateColumn(boolean corporateColumn) {
        this.corporateColumn = corporateColumn;
}
```

**In ReportController.java ;**

```
boolean corporateColumn = reportDTO.isCorporateColumn(); // this evaluates to false
//Which expected as true when corporateColumn checkbox is checked
```

Everything works fine unless it is used as disabled="true" (/ disabled="${'true'}")  for checkbox field.

I had the similar issue previously also when getting the value of a disabled textfield and overcome it by making the field readonly.
So I am not sure in Spring MVC whether it is not possible to get the value of input field when it is disabled.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's sorry to say that but that's impossible.

Use developer tool(like in Chrome) to check posted data, you can confirm browser will not send your checkbox's data if it's disabled or unchecked.

Why don't you simply use 'readonly' instead of 'disabled'?

Comment: Actually I wanted use it as disabled as my client wanted to do so. But now I think rather to bothering about that it is better to make it readonly as you suggested. Thank you very much for clarifying me the thing.

Comment: P.S. As readonly="true" doesn't work on checkboxes I overcome it as  <input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" />   which was found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Answer (score 3):

Disabled field data is not passed on to server.