# Why is the HTML form input attribute "readonly" only supported for input and textarea elements?

Tags: html, w3c

Can anyone please explain to me the rational as to why in the [W3C HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly) the HTML form input attribute "readonly" is only supported for input and textarea elements?

Why would it be wrong for a radio button to be readonly?

Comment: It's similar, @mcv asked at the end of his question "Incidentally, does anyone know why readonly doesn't work in radio buttons, while it does work in other input tags? Is this one of those incomprehensible omissions in the HTML specs?" but this part of his questions was IMO never satisfactorily answered.

Comment: The HTML5 spec explains it: "The difference between disabled and readonly is that read-only controls are still focusable, so the user can still select the text and interact with it, whereas disabled controls are entirely non-interactive. (For this reason, only text controls can be made read-only: it wouldn't make sense for checkboxes or buttons, for instances."

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly