# HTML Checkbox Click() Return FALSE or TRUE instead of READONLY or DISABLED using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, toggle

Since I don't have enough points to leave a comment, I must ask a question. The situation I'm referencing can be seen here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027466/2748356). And I promise that I've Googled for hours before posting a question.

I'm trying to be able to "toggle" HTML checkboxes to be readonly. Here is where I am so far.

1. "DISABLED" is NOT an option. It won't post with the form.
2. "READONLY" is NOT really readonly. It may gray-out, but it can still be clicked.
3. The only thing that seems to work is what the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027466/2748356) refers to and that is applying READONLY to the checkboxes and then some jQuery like:
   `$(':checkbox[readonly=readonly]').click(function(){return false;});` or `$(':checkbox[readonly=readonly]').click(function(){return true;});`

   - I've also messed around with swapping classes in case there was something limiting about the readonly attribute.

**THE PROBLEM** is that whatever the first setting becomes (TRUE or FALSE) is what it stays like until the page is refreshed. I **can't** re-enable the checkboxes simply by running the other statement to return the opposite (FALSE or TRUE).

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is there a way to be able to toggle the RETURN (TRUE or FALSE) for the .click event?
2. Is there another alternative for toggling the ability to check the checkboxes?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: always use `.change()` for handling checkbox events

Comment: The `.change()` is irrelevant. It's the .click() functionality that needs to be disabled without actually making the checkbox disabled for the form.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CsMJh/)

If you want to toggle between `return false;` & `return true;` you could use `.change()` event & come up with a specific condition to toggle.

```
$(':checkbox[readonly=readonly]').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        console.log("return false");
    else
        console.log("return true");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Krishna, but this isn't really what I'm asking. This solution returns a true/false value from a specific checkbox. It's the click event that needs to be disabled so the user can't check the checkbox. If you add the disabled attribute the checkbox won't post with the form and readonly doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK finally figured it out. I'll try to keep my points organized.

1. Include *jquery-ui.js*, not sure why, but it needs it.
2. Use a .change() event to add and remove two classes that designate READ/WRITE
3. Use `$('.ReadClass').bind('click',false);` to prevent *checking*
4. Use `$('.ReadClass').unbind('click', false);` **AND** *switch the classes* **AND** add `$('.WriteClass').bind('click',true);` to en-enabled *checking*

[**Here is a link to my jsFiddle demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/polishcrab/fKPfr/1/) 
*The demo loops through all specified form element to toggle the ability for the user to enter data.*

Hope this helps somebody else.