# Checkboxes Remain Ticked If Untick

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I want to make checkboxes so they should remain `ticked` even if someone try to `untick` them. My HTML is;

```
<fieldset class="trow2">
<legend><strong>{$lang->account_prefs}</strong></legend>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" width="100%">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="allownotices" id="allownotices" value="1" {$allownoticescheck} /></td>
<td valign="top"><span class="smalltext"><label for="allownotices">{$lang->allow_notices}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="receivepms" id="receivepms" value="1" {$receivepmscheck} /></td>
<td valign="top"><span class="smalltext"><label for="receivepms">{$lang->receive_pms}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="pmnotice" id="pmnotice" value="1"{$pmnoticecheck} /></td>
<td valign="top"><span class="smalltext"><label for="pmnotice">{$lang->pm_notice}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="emailpmnotify" id="emailpmnotify" value="1" checked="checked" {$emailpmnotifycheck} /></td>
<td valign="top"><span class="smalltext"><label for="emailpmnotify">{$lang->email_notify_newpm}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><span class="smalltext"><label for="subscriptionmethod">{$lang->subscription_method}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <select name="subscriptionmethod" id="subscriptionmethod">
        <option value="2" {$instant_email_subscribe_selected}>{$lang->instant_email_subscribe}</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</fieldset>
```

If I try to use `DISABLED` attribute in `input` tag then the value can't pass through the script, and on the other hand I do not want to use `HIDDEN` attribute in `input` because it hides the checkboxes which I do not want to do like that, I want to show checkboxes, ticked by default but the users shouldn't able to untick them.

I'm satisfied if someone provide me the solution using jQuery.

Please help!

Comment: Well.. There are an article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly
It should help you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for all checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" onclick="return false" />
```

Output: http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/HKML5/

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thank You Zword, your solution has little code but effective! :)

Comment: Accept answer if its what you needed @user2854563

Comment: @user2854563 the only thing is it doesn't allow someone to initially tick the box...?

Comment: Oh i forgot that @user2854563

Comment: @metsales i answered for what the user asked for.

Comment: @Zword wasn't saying you were wrong, was just trying to make sure its what the OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

Since you're open to using jQuery, try:

```
$('input[checked=checked]').click(function() {return false;});
```

That will prevent clicks from registering on the input itself. You may need to add a similar handler on the label since browsers will change input state with clicks there as well.

But, there's still a question whether this is really the best approach. See the discussions here: [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Answer (score 0):

When user tries to change the checkbox value to false, the `change` event is triggered you can always set it to true using `prop`

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
     $(this).prop("checked",true);
})
```