# simple_form dynamic readonly on association attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

In `simple_form` if you supply an array to the disabled option...it will disable any association object created that is in the array.  The same does not seem true for the readonly option.

this, for example, does what you would expect

```
f.association :items, collection: @items, as: :check_boxes, disabled: @used_items
```

however, this does not do what I would expect...

```
f.association :items, collection: @items, as: :check_boxes, readonly: @used_items
```

I set options using checkboxes, if the id is not passed back in the edit action...the record is deleted.  Therefore, I can not use the disabled option.  But, I can't seem to make this work using readonly.

Anyone know the trick??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readonly` is not a valid attribute for checkboxes, see [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

The solution suggested there is to have a disabled checkbox and a hidden input with the desired name to make sure the value is submitted.

Comment: A disabled checkbox with a hidden field is definitely the way to go.  I ended up altering my approach to solving this problem but, your answer is spot on.