# HTML: Why there is no native support to restrict state change in check-box without disabling it?

Tags: html

In HTML, only text controls like text-box, text-area, password-box have read-only property. Why didn't they support check-box/radio-button?

I know I can achieve this feature using script by putting onclick="return false;". (I don't want any workaround, I want to know only the reason for not providing native support to achieve this)

But my question is there any specific reason for not supporting read-only in check-box/ radio button even-though it accepts input from user.

**EDIT 1:**
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly) but it doesn't answer my question - *Why there is no native way to restrict the user to change the state without disabling it?*

Comment: How about using the attribute `disabled` ?

Comment: Its working readonly option for check box and radio button also

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited to programmers. It's about speculating on the decisions made by language designers a decade+ ago, not a practical problem that can be solved.

Comment: @RossBille — No, it isn't a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Rob, If i put disabled on postback it will not get submitted

Comment: My question is why didn't give this feature just to prevent changing the state?

Comment: sorry, I am not creator of the `markup` :(

Comment: @Quentin It looks like a dupe to me.

Comment: @krishna, yeah, but `readonly` on a checkbox doesn't make sense either ( what exactly are you going to copy?  ). Use a hidden field, or un disable on submit.

Comment: @krishna, but I can see where you are coming from

Comment: @Chris — The question is asking why there isn't a working native attribute, not what the alternatives are.

Comment: @Quentin The highest voted answer there quotes the same source as the highest voted answer here, which explains pretty clearly *why* -- you can't change the value of a checkbox, so `readonly` is illogical. They are always read only.

Comment: @Chris, How it'd be illogical chris! then wat w3c offers me to restrict user not to change the state? what is the native way to restrict user not to change the state?

Comment: The `disabled` property prevents interaction, which includes changing the state. The `readonly` property prevents changing the value, but **allows** interaction - eg, changing the state. Checking a checkbox does not change the *value* of the checkbox, it changes the state. The value is whatever the `value` property is set as, and there is never a circumstance in which the user can edit the value of a checkbox, unlike a textarea for instance. Thus, it is not logical to implement `readonly` on an element that is inherently read-only by design.

Comment: @Chris, Ur explanation is pretty clear. Thank u very much. Then If i dont want to disable(because i need the value to be submited on postback) there is no native way to prevent interaction right? Pls corrct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: That's correct. You can either use the `onclick` workaround, or `onsubmit` your form can remove the `disabled` attribute on all the elements really quick. Something to consider: why are you putting a value that you need in a checkbox that the user cannot interact with? Just use a hidden form element. Better still, put the value in session, or the database so the user can't mess with it at all. I can't imagine your use case, it sounds like you might have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/163135) -- question your approach.

Comment: Can anyone tell, why is this Duplicate not removed still? I edited the Question? Is it still really seems to be duplicate? I really didn't get the answer for my question what i meant?

Comment: @Quentin - Suggest me something,  I want the duplicate to be removed.

Comment: @krishna — Read the answers you've got. Jukka's seems to answer it. Accept it. Stop worrying about the duplicateness.

Comment: @Quentin - No, I'm really asking different question Quentin. Am not asking abt why read-only is not supported here rather, why didn't they consider giving native way for restricting the state change? I agree Jukka's answer is satisfying. I'm still expecting better one.

Comment: @krishna — He's got a link to a discussion about it by the spec developers. You're not likely to get a better answer than that without some kind of telepathy + time machine so you can read the minds of everyone involved in the development of browsers and HTML.

Comment: @Quentin - So, Is this site not the right place for asking such question or what?

Comment: Technically, this question is not a duplicate of `Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?`, because it asks why, not how, which goes to the reasoning for the functionality, and not to how to work around its limitations.

Answer (score 2):

> It's important to understand that READONLY merely prevents the user
>   from changing the value of the field, not from interacting with the
>   field. For many types of fields, READONLY is irrelevent because you
>   don't normally change the value. In checkboxes, for example, you can
>   check them on or off (thus setting the CHECKED state) but you don't
>   change the value of the field. DISABLED, however, actually prevents
>   you from using the field.
>
> Notice in these examples that you can set the checkboxes even though
>   they are "read only":

### [SOURCE](http://www.faqs.org/docs/htmltut/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html)

[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/sutagegu/1/) from faqs.org

Answer (score 2):

[HTML 4.01 allows `readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) for `input` in general without restrictions by type. However, it seems that it was generally not implemented in browsers, possibly because the implementors did not see much need for it. In HTML5 CR, `readonly` is explicitly [disallowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#checkbox-state-%28type=checkbox%29) for `input type=checkbox`, and HTML5 CR (or some other “HTML5 spec” such as HTML 5.1 Nightly or WHATWG Living HTML) is generally what implementors use as the guideline these days.

There have been proposals to allow it in HTML5, e.g. a [discussion](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-May/date.html#243164) in May 2011 at the whatwg list, as well as browser bug reports (rejected on the basis of what HTML5 says), but apparently without sufficiently good use cases. Although real use cases exist, they are probably too marginal, and reasonable alternatives can be presented, such as the use of a checkbox image (checked or unchecked as desired) with suitable associated text and, if the pseudo-checkbox is set to checked, a hidden field carrying the desired information.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to make it disable(readonly) or enable. Only text fields are possible to make them readable at the time of rendering.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1"/>
```

then by using Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#chk1").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: The question is asking **why** the feature isn't native, it isn't looking for workarounds (it even mentions a work around in the question itself!).

Comment: You don't have to go through this... <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" disabled/> would work.. BTW you are missing # in selector

Comment: @azhar, Even i achecived this feature using some script. but i just want to kno why didnt this feature be implemented and why didn't they design it like just to prevent user to change the state?

Comment: @krishna actually textfields are readonly property because we restrict our user to enter any text by making it readonly in case of checkboxes and radiobuttons no text is added by keyboard or any source.
If you think about read/write these properties are associated with any type of file and file contain some text(in the form of charcters)
while textbox, textarea's, also contains text(in the form of characters) that's why they have readonly property.

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't intersect the `onclick` event of a checkbox for the mere purpose of checking whether it is checked or not. You should use the `onchange` event instead. Why? Because the `onclick` event triggers before the `onchange` event, so if you intersect the `onclick` event you will not be able to get the actual state of the checkbox unless you do some ugly javascript acrobatics with `setTimeout`

If you want to make the checkbox "read-only" you have to use the `disabled` attribute. Like below...

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled/>
```

To answer your question, I think it's better explained by the [HTML Specs in W3.Org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute)

> The difference between disabled and readonly is that read-only controls are still focusable, so the user can still select the text and interact with it, whereas disabled controls are entirely non-interactive. (For this reason, only text controls can be made read-only: it wouldn't make sense for checkboxes or buttons, for instances.)

Comment: I know the difference what u mentioned, but why didn't they design it like just to prevent user to change the state?

Comment: I'm not an advocate of the WWW3 Standards and I didn't even participate in the design of these standards so I can't tell you why or how they arrived to this conclusion/outcome while brainstorming the specs. The explanation seems clear to me...DISABLED = NO INTERACTION...while READ-ONLY = INTERACT BUT DON't CHANGE. If you really understand the difference you wouldn't be asking yourself why