# RubyOnRails Form_for check_box_tag disabled Checkbox POST submit

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, form-for

i create a check_box_tag and set it to checked and disabled that it is set and the user cannot change the state of the checkbox.
[image]

```
          <% checkedDisabled = false
         if current_user.id == user.id
           checkedDisabled = true
         end
      %>

      <div>
        <%= check_box_tag "book[user_ids][]", user.id, @book.users.include?(user), {checked: checkedDisabled, disabled: checkedDisabled}  %>
        <%= user.email %>
      </div>
```

[image: The checkbox is checked and disabled]
The checkbox where the current user == the user in the array is checked and disabled

The problem is that if I submit the form the disabled checkbox gets not submitted as checked.
How can I solve this. I used read only but then you can still uncheck the checkbox ( even it gets submitted as checked.

I need a way to remove the `disabled` tag from the checkbox before i submit.

Comment: One solution would be to have a javascript click event listener on these check boxes, which would `return false` if it's `checked` and has `readonly=true`.

Answer (score 0):

Form fields that are disabled are not submitted, so you dont want to use that. On text fields, select boxes, etc. you can use `readonly` to get the desired effect, however that doesnt work as expected for check boxes. See this answer for more info: [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

A workaround is to disable the check_box and then store the value in a hidden field, something like this:

```
 <%= check_box_tag "book[user_ids][]", user.id, @book.users.include?(user), {checked: checkedDisabled, disabled: checkedDisabled}  %>
<% if checkedDisabled %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "book[user_ids][]", user.id, value: @book.users.include?(user)  %>
<% end %>
```