# Unable to change the property of a checkbox to readOnly

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML in which I have table, one column of table contains checkboxes and other contains text.

One checkbox is coming auto punched from the backend when the page loads. I want to make that checkbox readonly. below is the code I am using but its not working. 
pls suggest.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr td').each(function(){
    $('this').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('readOnly',true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using a string for `'this'` and the weird camel-casing (which doesn't really matter, both because the HTML **isn't** case-sensitive and also because jQuery fixes it to lowercase anyway) there's the simple fact that **there's no such thing as a readonly checkbox**. [See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/2fp52v79/) (if you're interested why - simply put, READONLY prevents changing the field's *value* - and when clicking on a checkbox you're actually [changing its *state*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155301/2387772))

Instead, use disabled:

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$('this').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('readOnly',true);
```

to this

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: it is still not working for me, below is my updated code.

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr td').each(function(){
    $('this').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('readonly',true);
  });
});

Comment: @Vaibhav...try yuvi's answer,,

Answer (score 0):

return false on click event...

Try this:

```
$('tr td').each(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').on('click', function(){ return false });
});
```

[**::JsFiddle::**](http://jsfiddle.net/xn6wjcqx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to disable all checkboxes

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('disabled', "true");
```