# Deny to change the state of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need to deny to change the state of any checkbox:

```js
window.doNotChange = function(event) {
  e = event || window.event;
  if (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(e.target);
    t.prop({checked: typeof t.attr('checked') != 'undefined'});
  }
  alert('Deny to change THIS checkbox!');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" checked onchange="doNotChange(event)"> name 1 (readonly)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="doNotChange(event)"> name 2 (readonly)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" checked> name 3 (editable)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" checked onchange="doNotChange(event)"> name 4 (readonly)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox"> name 5 (editable)</label></p>
<p>etc.</p>
```

This code works. But is there a better solution?

Comment: I am embarrassed by this code: t.prop({checked: typeof t.attr('checked') != 'undefined'});

Comment: Yeah. I'm too. Couldn't understand the logic.

Comment: Any checkboxes, in which I added onchange-event, must be readonly. And on click them must be an alert.

Answer (score 3):

Just use HTML's `disabled` attribute:

```html
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
```

Comment: Because `readonly` only prevents changes to the *`value`* of an `<input />`, it doesn't prevent changes to the *state* (`checked` or not). Sadly. See the Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Comment: I may be incorrectly set the task. I need to display a message on click to the checkbox. And disabled is not suitable for me.

Comment: @ВолошенкоОлег you can display a message on click by binding on click.

Comment: "disabled" attribute disables "onclick" event too

Answer (score 0):

How about just simple disable the ones you don't wan't changes on:

```
document.getElementById("your_field_id").disabled = true;
```

Comment: "disabled" property is not suitable for me. I did it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Now, I see only one solution: to transfer the element and the default value to the function

```js
window.doNotChange=function(el,v){
 $(el).prop({checked:v});
 alert('Can\'t touch this');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" checked onchange="doNotChange(this,1)"> name 1 (readonly)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="doNotChange(this,0)"> name 2 (readonly)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" checked> name 3 (editable)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" checked onchange="doNotChange(this,1)"> name 4 (readonly)</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox"> name 5 (editable)</label></p>
```

Thanks for answers