# Simple .prop trigger for checkbox with checked and readonly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

```js
$(function() {

  $("#all").click(function() {
    $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="sb_dropdown">
  <li class="sb_filter">Filter your search</li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx" id="all" type="checkbox">
    <label for="all"><strong>Show All</strong>
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Activated" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Activated">Activated</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Deactivated" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Deactivated">Deactivated</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Blocked" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Blocked">Blocked</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Locked" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Locked">Locked</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Simple .prop() problem here

```
$("#all").click(function () {
    $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

how to add readonly + checked, 
all .chechboxClass is checkbox and when i click the #all id all checkboxClass is turn into checked with readonly. I think something missing in $("#all").

> **Update** Sorry i didn't note that $("#all") is an toggle for all
>   checkboxes

Comment: Did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple properties to `prop()` like below, base the value of checked and readonly on the checked state of the `#all` element like

```js
$("#all").click(function() {
  $(".checkBoxClass").prop({
    checked: this.checked
      //, disabled: this.checked if it fits your need
  });

});

//to make it non editable another choice is to use disabled property if it fits your need
$(".checkBoxClass").click(function() {
  return !$("#all").is(':checked')
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sb_dropdown">
  <li class="sb_filter">Filter your search</li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx" id="all" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="all"><strong>Show All</strong>
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Activated" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="Activated">Activated</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Deactivated" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="Deactivated">Deactivated</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Blocked" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="Blocked">Blocked</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="chkbx checkBoxClass" id="Locked" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="Locked">Locked</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Input.readOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-readonly)

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the user cannot modify the value
>   of the control. It is ignored if the value of the type attribute is
>   hidden, range, color, checkbox, radio, file, or a button type (such as
>   button or submit).

- [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Comment: `when i click the #all id all checkboxClass is turn into checked with readonly.`. The state of `#all` has nothing to do with the other checkboxex. Atleast not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments inline in the code:

```
$("#all").click(function() {
    $(".checkBoxClass").prop({ // Set properties of all the checkboxes having class checkBoxClass 
        'checked': true, // Set the checked property to true
        'readonly': true // Make the checkboxes readonly
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<th><input type="checkbox" class="user"><th>

<td><input class="email" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $object['email']; ?>"></td>

$(".user").click(function () {
    $(".email").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```