# ng-readonly not working in angular checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Can I use ng-readonly directive in a checkbox?

The checkbox is writable even after it is decorated with ng-readonly.

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model" ng-readonly="test" /> {{model}}
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = true;
});
```

Added [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19998/)

Comment: add ng-model to your input field

Comment: Aparently ng-readonly is not working for checkboxes, you can use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

if you want to disable it use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="test" />
```

Answer (score 11):

If you like to have it "more" visible, you can always use a little javascript trick:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model" onclick="return false;" />
```

Comment: Much better and cleaner solution.

Comment: In no case do not! Violate the work of the framework

Answer (score 7):

ng-readonly only work with input type="text"

see documentation here -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

The HTML specification does not require browsers to preserve the values of boolean attributes such as readonly. (Their presence means true and their absence means false.) If we put an Angular interpolation expression into such an attribute then the binding information would be lost when the browser removes the attribute. `The ngReadonly directive solves this problem for the readonly attribute`. This complementary directive is not removed by the browser and so provides a permanent reliable place to store the binding information.

Comment: Current documentation 1.5.8 (which your link is pointing to) does not mention such constraint, but it's actually effective. (doc improvement needed?)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did this, and it worked for me. I think that way I don't directly access the DOM. If someone see any error, please let me know. Thanks.

> HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" id="name" [checked]="true" (click)="onNoClick($event)">
```

> TypeScript

```
  onNoClick(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
md-checkbox[ng-readonly="true"]{
    z-index: -1;
}
```

or

```
md-checkbox[ng-readonly="true"]{
     pointer-events: none
}
```

The last, doesn't work in IE

Answer (score 0):

Also try `[attr.disabled]`;

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.disabled]="true"> </input>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).