# How to forbid unchecking checkbox's element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Is it possible to forbid some action on checkbox? For example I want to leave $('#post-id') and $('#activation') checkboxes always checked, without any possibilities to uncheck them?

```
$("#activation").attr("checked", true);
$("#post-id").attr("checked", true);
```

My example you can find here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9LzLm9hx/1/

Comment: Why not simply set the checkbox to disabled? This will stop the user clicking it, still allow its value to be submitted in a form, but also indicate to the user they can't interact with it. If you use some JavaScript to prevent it being unchecked they may perceive it as a bug as the UI doesn't indicate to them its non-intractable. EDIT: You will however have to have some validation where you use it, as potentially the user can 'un disable' it by simply opening dev tools.

Comment: If you don't want to disable them however for some reason, here's a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8zwoumtg/

Comment: @gearsdigital Readonly does not have any effect on checkboxes - you don't change their values, only their 'checked' state. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this

```
      $( '#common' ).on('click', function () {
        $( '.common-inputs [type="checkbox"]:not([disabled])' ).prop('checked', this.checked); 
      });

//checkbox
            $("#activation").attr("checked", true);
      $("#post-id").attr("checked", true);
      $("#activation").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#post-id").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `disabled` to the checkboxes in question.
They then have their default value, however, will not be editable anymore.

These are the changes in question:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="activation" name="check" disabled/>
```

This would be your updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9LzLm9hx/2/

Enjoy :)

Comment: this will be edited by the function in the click event, you're missing a selector in your fiddle

Comment: Oh, did not know about this @gearsdigital.
One could however simply put a hidden field with default values that then do transmit the data :)

Comment: @gearsdigital No, readonly does not do *anything* for checkboxes. Readonly only prevents the user from changing the value, but when you check checkboxes you change their checked state - their value remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet after checked true.

```
<script>
function HideandDisabled(){
    $("#activation").attr("checked", true);
    document.getElementById("activation").disabled=true;
    $("#post-id").attr("checked", true);
    document.getElementById("post-id").disabled=true;
}
</script>
```