# Make Checkbox Readonly Mode with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code.  How can I make my checkbox readonly mode so that user cannot edit again?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tog_gmat"
       <?php 
           if($gmat_flag == 1) 
              {
                echo "checked";
              } 

        ?> 
class="chk" value="GMAT">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add attribute `disabled="disabled"`. But be aware that disabled checkbox does not send value via POST.

Answer (score 1):

Just return `false` when clicked

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" id="tog_gmat" <?php if($gmat_flag == 1){echo "checked";} ?> class="chk" value="GMAT">
```

Or with jQuery.

```
$('#tog_gmat').on('click', function() {
    return false;
})
```

**Update**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tog_gmat" <?php if($gmat_flag == 1){echo "checked onclick='return false'";} ?> class="chk" value="GMAT">
```

Comment: How can you make the same process in PHP instead Javascript?? And i want to prevent the checkbox from editing??

Comment: Use that first method `onclick="return false"`.

Comment: If i use that method means even in case of unchecked.we cannot edit checkbox right????