# How to make checkbox readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with with two fields one is radio button and second one is checkbox. I want to make checkbox unchecked(If checked) and readonly when radio button value is No. My code is working for unchecked functionality but readonly does not work.Please help me

This is my code:

Html :

```
<input type="radio" name="data[User][email_status]" id="" value="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="data[User][email_status]" id="" value="no" checked="checked">No 
<input type="checkbox" name="data[User][no_alerts]" id="" value="yes">
```

Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="data[User][email_status]"]').change (function(){
        //console.log($(this).val());
        if ($(this).val() == 'no')  {
            $('input[name="data[User][no_alerts]"]').attr({
                'checked' : false,
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to disable the checkbox

Comment: Example :  $('input[class="busiProp"]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled',true);

Comment: Note: making an input element `disabled` will not submit it with the form. Thus, a `checked` checkbox that is also `disabled` will behave as if it were unchecked. Which is fine for the purposes of this question (given the description), but is not fine for the general case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Answer (score 3):

Use the disabled property to make the input readonly

```js
  $('input[value="no"]:checked').next().prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="data[User][email_status]" id="" value="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="data[User][email_status]" id="" value="no" checked="checked">No
<input type="checkbox" name="data[User][no_alerts]" id="" value="yes">
```

or a more general approach

```
 $('input[value="no"]:checked').parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: The checkbox is not necessarily placed right after (hence `.next()`) the `input[value="no"]`. You may want to consider some degree of generality in your answer

Comment: @Trix i don't want to :)

Comment: Be advised: [disabled form inputs are not posted with form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="data[User][no_alerts]"]').attr({
                'disabled' : true,
            });
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using jQuery instead of HTML to make the input disabled? Why not using `<input type="checkbox" disabled>`

Answer (score -1):

You may like this code snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  var chk = $('input[name="data[User][no_alerts]"]');//got check-box
  $('input[name="data[User][email_status]"]').on('change', function(e) {
    chk.prop('disabled', false); //enable first
    if ('no' == this.value) {
      chk.prop({
        'disabled': true,
        'checked': false
      });
    }
  });
  $('input[name="data[User][email_status]"]:checked').trigger('change');//fire code on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="data[User][email_status]" id="" value="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="data[User][email_status]" id="" value="no" checked="checked">No
<input type="checkbox" name="data[User][no_alerts]" id="" value="yes">
```

Comment: @Trix, as per OP, checkbox needs to be readonly if the answer is **NO** . Now what if the user wanna change his/her option from **No** to **Yes**?

Answer (score -1):

**this can also be used**

```
 $('input[name="data[User][email_status]"]').change (function(){
            //console.log($(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() == 'no')  {
                $('input[name="data[User][no_alerts]"]').attr({
                    'checked' : false,
                    'disabled':"disabled",
                });
            }
        });
```