# Trying to disable all the input=text fields except one input control in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am trying to do is something like this

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"],textarea').not(data-value="SHControl").attr('readonly','readonly');
```

Please provide me the correct syntax to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the syntax for using `.not` in jQuery. What you want to do is this:

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"],textarea').not('[data-value=SHControl]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Created a jsfiddle here to show how it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/clausjensen/e24seukm/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"],textarea').each(function() {
  var el = $(this);

  el.prop("readonly", el.data("value") !== "SHControl");
})
```

```css
*[readonly] {
  border: solid 1px red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" data-value="SHControl" />
<textarea></textarea>
```

A checkbox has no `readonly` state as this only prevents the manipulation of the `value` attribute ->
[Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Answer (score 0):

hello this the solution of added readonly

```
 <style>
    *[readonly] {
  border: solid 1px red
}
    </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.test').each(function(index, element) {

        if($(this).attr('data-value')!="SHControl"){
            $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
        }
    });
});
 </script>


 <input class="test" type="text" data-value="SHControl"/>
 <input class="test" type="checkbox" data-value="SHControl"/>

 <textarea class="test" data-value="SHControl" ></textarea>

 <input class="test" type="text" data-value="SHControl1"/>
 <input class="test" type="checkbox" data-value="SHControl1"/>

 <textarea class="test" data-value="SHControl1" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='checkbox'], textarea").not("input[data-value='SHControl']").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```