# i need help for checkbox in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm listing the data in database by using checkbox, but the checkbox need to be locked. How Can I do this?

My code looks like the following:

```
<td align="center">
    @Html.CheckBox("WordSwap",@item.WordSwap)
</td>
```

Comment: you mean read only?

Comment: Check here:[Readonly-check boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly) it looks like what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that you mean `read-only`, you can use the following syntax:

```
@Html.CheckBox("WordSwap", @item.WordSwap, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: Thanks for help!

Comment: @ErhanAŞKIN  no problem. Please don't forget to mark as answered.