# How prevent user to toggle a checkbox button created useing bootstrap buttongroups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a [boostrap buttongroup for checkboxes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio), like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d1" />1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d2" />2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d3" />3</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d4" />4</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d5" />5</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d6" />6</label>
</div>
```

I would like to disable some of them using Js. I already tried:

```
$("#d2").attr("locked", true);
$("#d2").attr('disabled', true);
$("#d2").parent().attr('disabled', true);
$("#d2").parent().addClass('disabled');
```

It shows button as disabled HOWEVER it does not removes the functionality of it. when I click it still toggles the `active` state.

Disabled button 2

[image: Disabled button 2]

Disabled button 2 after click

[image: Disabled button 2 after click]

How can I prevent user to toggle it? Here are an snippet exemple of this issue.

```js
$("#d2").prop("checked", false);
$("#d2").prop("locked", true);
$("#d2").prop("disabled", true);
$("#d2").parent().prop('disabled', true);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green!important;
  color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d1" />1</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d2" />2</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d3" />3</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d4" />4</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d5" />5</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" id="d6" />6</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding bootstrap `disabled` class

Comment: @Prajwal, adding disabled class don't turns off toggle functionality

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
$("#d2").prop('disabled', true);
```

This works for me.

Comment: sorry. it doesn't works. Take a look at the snippet.