# How to toggle readonly state of check box in javascript

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I understood that adding `readonly` attribute to check box does not make it readonly. Also adding `disable` attribute will not post the value.

On this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly) there are different options suggested to make the check box readonly.

However, i want to toggle the readonly state of the check box on some button click, and also post the value on form submit.

So as suggested i added "return false" on click event. Works fine. However how do i toggle this behavior?

```
<button type="button" id="btn">Toggle</button>
<input type="checkbox" value="false" onClick="return false;" name="CheckBox1" />


$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#btn").click(function()
   {
      //how do i toggle readonly here
   })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to toggle a classname on the checkbox, then test for the presence of that classname when the user tries to change the checkbox state.

(You could use a data attribute instead, but this way has the added benefit of letting you give the user some visual cue that the input is readonly.)

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $('input[name="CheckBox1"]').toggleClass("readonly");
});

$('input[name="CheckBox1"]').on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('readonly')) {return false}
});
```

```css
.readonly {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Toggle</button>
<input type="checkbox" value="false" name="CheckBox1" />
```