# Other way to disable checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Besides the regular `disabled` property, is there any other way to "disable" a checkbox visually and functionally?

I'm just wondering if there's something like `readonly` for checkbox. I'm developing this module where a checkbox is disabled when either of the 2 unrelated conditions are met. I just want to keep it simple without writing some more codes and all.

Plan is, 1 condition triggers the `disabled` property and the other one triggers the "disabled2" property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Comment: READONLY doesn't work on checkboxes as it prevents you from editing a field's value, but with a checkbox you're actually editing the field's state (on || off)

Comment: Whats wrong with disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The pointer-events property is used to control under what conditions
>   particular graphic elements can become the target of pointer events.

Syntax: Formal Syntax:
pointer-events: visiblePainted | visibleFill | visibleStroke | visible |
painted | fill | stroke | all | none | inherit

The values in the official syntax are applicable to SVG elements. Of these values, only these are applicable to HTML:

pointer-events: auto | none | inherit

Initial: auto
Applies To: all elements
Animatable: no

```css
.Disable{pointer-events:none;opacity:0.7 }
.Disable+ span{opacity:0.6 }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<span>checkbox1</span>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Disable"/>
<span >checkbox2</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add following  CSS property to div containing checkbox

```
  pointer-events:none
```

Then it will be disabled.