# How to make a checkbox checked and disabled?

Tags: php

I have tried:

```
<input disabled='disabled' 
checked='checked' 
type='checkbox' 
name='checkTema[]' 
value=".$cat->cat_ID."> ".$cat->name."<br>"
```

But that won't pick up the value when I send the form

**UPDATE**

Thanks to a comment I've got a helping answer from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly), yet I am not sure how I should be applying the trick, tried the following but not sending the value

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='checkTema[]' value='1' >";
echo "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' disabled='disabled' name='checkTema[]' value=".$cat->cat_ID."> ".$cat->name."<br>";
```

Comment: @SougataBose `readonly` isn't picked up by the input `<input readonly checked='checked' type='checkbox' name='checkTema[]' value=".$cat->cat_ID."> ".$cat->name."<br>";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Comment: `readonly` doesn't work on checkboxes. See my flagged duplicate for workarounds for this problem

Comment: I was not aware of that. Then you can use some hidden fields and jquery for this purpose.

Comment: @Nick thanks, saw that answer, but I don't want to use JavaScript, and I am using wrongly the hidden field trick. See updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you need to POST disabled checkboxes, I suggest using a hidden input before:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox_disabled" value="<?php echo $checkbox_value; ?>" /> <== Checked and disabled
```

Then in your PHP code, you can simply check:

```
if ($_POST['checkbox']) {
  //Checkbox wasn't disabled on submission
} else {
  //Fallback to using the disabled value:
  $disabledVal = $_POST['checkbox_disabled'];
}
```

Additionally, you can simply undisable all the elements of the form before submission:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $(this).find('input').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155301/4875631) for more information on how you can alternatively do this.

Comment: But would it post the values?

Comment: this won't POST the value

Comment: yes thanks, see my updated question, I believe I am using wrongly the hidden field trick. There is another answer on here and also taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6905050/1018804 which works by using javascript but I wanted to avoid JS

Comment: @rob.m So is it not working? Your code posted should indeed work. `print_r($_POST);` and show the values.

Comment: i've answered myself

Comment: @rob.m So pretty much my answer

Comment: yes indeed, yet mine follows the exact code I had and it might be clearer for future users ending up on here. Thanks a lot tho

Answer (score 0):

Try return false in onclick event

```
 <input 
     onclick="return false"
    checked='checked' 
    type='checkbox' 
    name='checkTema[]' 
    value='.$cat->cat_ID.'> ".$cat->name."<br>"
```

Comment: well I'll be honest with you, this works as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/6905050/1018804 but I didn't want to use javascript. See my updated question as I believe I used wrongly the hidden field trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<input disabled='disabled' checked='checked' type='checkbox' name='checkTema[]' value="<?php echo $cat->cat_ID;?>"><?php echo $cat->name;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment, I've got the solution in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Then my code changed to:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='checkTema[]' value=".$cat->cat_ID." >";
echo "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' disabled='disabled'> ".$cat->name."<br>";
```