# Disable checkbox by passing the value

Tags: javascript, php

As the title suggests, I have a form, which as soon as the user registers he is forced to compile, then the user can return to this form, and obviously the form on the screen will present the choices that the user has previously made, now to make that the checkbox is enabled if the user has previously pressed on the checkbox, I succeed with this code here, and the checkbox, appears to me on the selected screen:

```
<input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_mostra_tabella_email['aut_privacy'],"S"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" id="aut_privacy" type="checkbox" value="S"  name="aut_privacy" >
```

the problem is that if I do the same thing with the disabled command, when the user presses enter, I don't pass the command value = "s".

I would just like the checkbox to be selected and disabled, how do I do it?

Comment: Please ask your question again, not understandable what you want...

Comment: I think you are looking for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Comment: @jameson2012 yes but not with html, because it s easy to pass, only php

Comment: What do you mean, not with html? How do you expect the phone script to know what was submitted without html? I would second @Marc and say you need to re-write your question

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, when you `disable` the element, it is not sent to the server.

There are a couple of things you could add to the element that would prevent user interaction. One is the style property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) and the other is the element attribute [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

If the input element has style property `pointer-events: none`, the user cannot access it with mouse click (or touch). WARNING: If the input has a label, the label is "clickable" too, in that case, suggest wrapping both in a `<div>` with that style property.

That will prevent the user from directly interacting with the element, but there is always tab. Use `tabindex=-1` so that the checkbox does not "*participate in sequential keyboard navigation*".

Answer (score 0):

Having read at Dino's answer I realise what you mean (I think).  The simplest way to do that is to display the checkbox as checked and disabled then add a hidden input with the correct name and value, that way the user cannot interact with the checkbox, but the value is sent back to php in the form submission.  If this isn't what you mean then you do need to re-write your question