# What is the way to get the Controlled Inputs behaviour in Svelte

Tags: svelte

What is the way in Svelte to get the Controlled Inputs behaviour (like [in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)).

I tried to prevent default checkbox behaviour on input click (prevents HTML checkbox to modify the checked prop).

```html
<input 
  type=checkbox 
  bind:checked={done} 
  on:click|preventDefault={() => dispatch('change'}}
  />
```

But apparently, it does something else - and svelte bindings stoped working.

Tried without `bind:checked` => just `checked={done}` - no results as well.

At the end I figured to do one-way binding via `if`:

```html
{#if done}
  <input type=checkbox checked readonly />
{:else}
  <input type=checkbox readonly />
{/if}
```

but that looks lame.

What is the proper way to implement `Controlled Inputs` in Svelte?

Full simplified example you could find here:
https://svelte.dev/repl/ecc812d1be34464185739f02ca2421cd?version=3.19.2

Comment: I found this post helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way this can be done is by turning off the pointer events for the checkbox and register a click event on a wrapper element that handles this.

```html
<style>
    input {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>

<label on:click|preventDefault={handleClick} on:keydown|preventDefault={handleClick}>
    <span>[current: {done}]</span>
    <input type="checkbox" checked={done}>
</label>
```

(I added the keydown handler so you can still toggle the checkbox with the keyboard as well)

Comment: oh, TIL that readonly on `:checkbox` is a react invention :D its not standard per-spec https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly :( therefore prob that is a nice addition. Wondering what svelte devs think :)

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to the value with `bind:checked={done}`, you're explicitly asking that the internal value of the checkbox be reflected to the `done` variable, so it seems to be the opposite of what you're asking.

To me, `preventDefault` seems like the way to go if you want to prevent the default input behaviour:

```html
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher()

    export let done;

    const handleClick = () => {
        dispatch('change');
    }

    const noop = () => {}
</script>

<div class="root" on:click={handleClick}>
    <label>


        <input type=checkbox checked={done} on:click|preventDefault={noop} />


        <slot></slot> [current: {done}]
    </label>
</div>
```

[Updated REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/65ea6b4f1f8343959e301ce2f7717779?version=3.19.2)

Maybe a more terse, old school, alternative could be this (notice, `onclick`, not `on:click`):

```html
<input type=checkbox checked={done} onclick="return false" />
```

In the context of Svelte, some might cringe at this and call it a code smell, though... But it feels OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can implement controlled input:

```html
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    export let checked = false;
    
    function handleChange(e) {
        const detail = e.target.checked;
        const ok = detail !== checked && dispatch('change', detail, { cancelable: true });
        ok || (e.target.checked = checked);
    }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" {checked} on:change={handleChange} />
```

And use it:

```html
<script>
    import Checkbox from './Checkbox.svelte';
    
    let checked = false;
    
    function handleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.detail);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>

<Checkbox {checked} on:change={handleChange} />
```

[REPL here](https://svelte.dev/repl/ac0c53c69fbc4b78adf39c901fe63dda?version=3.52.0)