# Why does :read-only selector affect elements which do not have readonly attribute?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="check-box">
      <input class="form-control input-text checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Contact Branch Specific Email field is required." id="UseBranchSpecificContact" name="UseBranchSpecificContact" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="UseBranchSpecificContact" type="hidden" value="false">
      <label for="UseBranchSpecificContact">Contact Branch Specific Email</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Which displays the following checkbox:

[image]

The checkbox is displayed using the following CSS:

```css
.check-box label:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdde3;
    content: '';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #3d4964;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

So the actual checkbox (input) is hidden and the above CSS adds a checkbox before the label. This is all working as expected.

I wanted to add an extra CSS class to change the color of displayed checkbox to light grey, if the label has `readonly` attribute. So I have added the following CSS:

```
.check-box label:read-only:before {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

But the problem is the above CSS affects the labels which do not have `readonly` attribute as well, I am not understanding why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Label' doesn't have 'readonly' attribute. As well, 'readonly' doesn't work with checkbox input type. You can use 'disabled' for checkbox.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("toggleBtn");
var input = document.getElementById("UseBranchSpecificContact");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  input.toggleAttribute("disabled");
});
```

```css
.check-box label:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdde3;
    content: '';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #3d4964;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.check-box input:disabled ~ label:before {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="check-box">
      <input class="form-control input-text checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Contact Branch Specific Email field is required." id="UseBranchSpecificContact" name="UseBranchSpecificContact" type="checkbox" value="true">
     <input name="UseBranchSpecificContact" type="hidden" value="false">
      <label for="UseBranchSpecificContact">Contact Branch Specific Email</label>
   </div>
</div>

<button id="toggleBtn">Toggle Disable</button>
```

Ref: [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Answer (score 0):

Tag 'label' doesn't have 'readonly' attribute. See html spec. If you want to change color of label, when input has 'readonly' attribute, than:
.check-box input[readOnly] + label {
...
}

Comment: Thanks, it would help if you could provide any reference/source

Comment: might be good to also point out that `:read-only` actually is `:not(:read-write)`, i.e all non editable elements do match.