# Why is :read-only CSS pseudo-class being applied on this checkbox?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I have the following SCSS code:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    ...
    &:read-only, &[readonly] {
        cursor: default;
        filter: grayscale(1);
    }
}
```

That is being applied to 
`<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onChange={this.rememberMe} />`

Following [MDN: :read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only) documentation:

> it will select any element that cannot be edited by the user.

#### Why is it being applied on my input that is editable?

The problem is applicable both to Firefox and Chrome.

[image: dev-tools]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Because `<input type="checkbox" />` and `<input type="radio" />` (and most other elements) are *inherently read-only*.
- Unlike an `<input type="text" />` or `<input type="date" />`, when you interact with (i.e. toggle) a checkbox or radio button you are not changing its `value`, you are changing its `checked` state.
- Yes, I agree it's counter-intuitive.

Consequently...

1. You **should not** apply the `<input readonly` attribute to a `radio` or `checkbox` for any purpose.

   - Because it won't do anything useful.
2. You **should not** define a CSS selector that uses the `:read-only` pseudo-class to select `<input>` elements that have an explicit HTML `<input readonly` attribute set.

   - Instead use the has-attribute-selector: `input[readonly]`.
   - It's probably a good idea just to avoid using the `:read-only` pseudo-class entirely [because it *also* selects pretty-much *every* HTML element on the page too; a function with little practical utility, imo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only).

---

From the current WHATWG HTML specification (emphasis mine, especially the last point):

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-read-only

> The `:read-write` pseudo-class must match any element falling into one of the following categories, which for the purposes of Selectors are thus considered user-alterable: [SELECTORS]
>
> - `<input>` elements to which the `<input readonly` attribute applies, and that are mutable (i.e. that do not have the `<input readonly` attribute specified and that are not `<input disabled`).
> - `<textarea>` elements that do not have a `<textarea readonly` attribute, and that are not `<textarea disabled`.
> - elements that are editing hosts or editable and are neither `<input>` elements nor `<textarea>` elements.
>
>   - [i.e. `contenteditable`]
> - **The `:read-only` pseudo-class must match all other HTML elements.**

---

Now, if you **want** a "*read-only checkbox/radio*" then you don't have too many *good* options, unfortunately; instead you have a mix of *terrible options* and barely-adequate ones...:

- [There is this popular QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly), however most of the highest-voted answers have suggestions that I think are *bad ideas*: such as depending upon a client-script to block user-interaction <sub>...[very imperfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6905050/159145) (from people who are ignorant of the fact a radio and checkbox can be manipulated in far, far more many ways than just `onclick`)</sub>, or using CSS's `pointer-events: none;` while *completely disregarding the fact that computer keyboards both exist and are regularly used by human computer operators*.
- The *least worst* suggestion, I think, is using `<input type="checkbox/radio" disabled />`, [as demonstrated with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155301/159145). ([The `<input type="hidden">` is necessary because disabled (and unchecked) inputs are not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424091/159145), which is another violation of the [*principle of least astonishment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) by the then-nascent browser vendors of the late-1990s.

---

If you want to use the `:read-only` pseudo-class on all `input` elements *except* radio and checkboxes then you need to think carefully (and test it too, using variations on `document.querySeletorAll("input:read-only")` in your browser's console!)

I recommend that you **do not** apply any styles using selectors for `input` elements without also explicitly specifying the `[type=""]` attribute selector - this is because styles with a selector like "`input`" (without any attribute-selectors) will be applied to future HTML input elements that we don't know about yet and could be introduced at any point in the near-future, and maybe next week Google Chrome adds a new `<input type="human-dna-sample" />` or Microsoft adds `<input type="clippy" />` to a particularly *retro* edition of their Edge browser - so you definitely don't want a `:read-only` style applied to those elements until you at least know how it will look and work - and so the browser will use its default/native styling which won't violate your users/visitor's expectations if they happen to come across it on your website at some point.

...so it means you need to write out rules for every known `<input type="...">` as repetitive `input[type=""]` style rules, and now you might wonder if there were any pseudo-classes for `input` elements based on their default native appearance because a lot of them sure do look share similar, if not identical, native appearance and visual-semantics (and shadow DOM structure, if applicable) - for example in desktop Chrome the input types `text`, `password`, `email`, `search`, `url`, `tel` and more are all clearly built around the same native *textbox* widget, so there *surely* must be a pseudo-class for different input "kinds", right? Something like `input:textbox-kind` for `text`, `password`, etc and `input:checkbox-kind` for `checkbox` and `radio` - unfortunately such a thing doesn't exist and if introduced tomorrow the W3C's CSS committee probably wouldn't approve it for a few more years at least - so until then we need to explicitly enumerate *every* `input[type=""]` that we know about so that we can accurately anticipate how browsers will render them with our `type=""`-specific style rules instead of throwing everything as `input {}` and seeing what sticks.

...fortunately the list isn't *[too long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)*, so I just wrote the rules out just now:

Feel free to copy + paste this; it's hardly even copyrightable. <sub>And I want to see how far this spreads across the Internet in my lifetime</sub>.

At the bottom is a CSS selector that will select only `<input` elements that are *from the future* by using an exhaustive set of `:not([type="..."])` selectors, as well as not matching `input` elements with an empty `type=""` attribute or missing one entirely.

```
/* Textbox-kind: */ 
input[type="text"]:read-only,
input[type="password"]:read-only,
input[type="search"]:read-only,
input[type="tel"]:read-only,
input[type="url"]:read-only,
input[type="email"]:read-only,
input[type="number"]:read-only {
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: 'not-allowed';
}

/* Date/time pickers: */ 
input[type="date"]:read-only,
input[type="datetime-local"]:read-only,
input[type="time"]:read-only,
input[type="week"]:read-only,
input[type="month"]:read-only {
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: 'not-allowed';
}

/* Button-kind (these are all practically obsolete now btw, as the <button> element is far, far, far superior in every way) */
input[type="button"]:disabled,
input[type="reset"]:disabled,
input[type="submit"]:disabled,
input[type="image"]:disabled {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px outset #666;
    cursor: 'not-allowed';
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

/* Checkbox-kind (Don't use `:read-only` with these): */
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled,
input[type="radio"]:disabled {
    /* I'm not setting any properties here because it's impossible to effectively style these elements without resorting to image-replacements using the `:checked` state in selectors for their parent or adjacent `<label>` or ::before/::after` of other proximate elements. */
}

/* Weird-stuff-kind: */ 
input[type="color"]:read-only,
input[type="file"]:read-only,
input[type="hidden"]:read-only,
input[type="range"]:read-only {
    /* Again, due to differences in how different browsers and platforms display (and consequently style) these inputs I don't think it's worth doing anything. */
}

/* If you **really** want to select _future_ <input> elements in-advance... do this: */

input[type]:not([type="text"]):not([type="password"]):not([type="search"]):not([type="tel"]):not([type="url"]):not([type="email"]):not([type="number"]):not([type="date"]):not([type="datetime-local"]):not([type="time"]):not([type="week"]):not([type="month"]):not([type="button"]):not([type="reset"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="image"]):not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="color"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="hidden"]):not([type="range"]) {

}
```

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you.