# Why is HTML select tag readonly by default?

Tags: html, css

Why is the `<select>` tag `readonly` by default?

```css
select:read-only {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="lizard">lizard</option>
    <option value="giraffe">giraffe</option>
    <option value="lion">lion</option>
</select>
```

My question is, if `<select>` doesn't have a readonly attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attributes) and the equivalent for it is `disabled`, then why the CSS selector works and the style is applied to it?

Comment: Because that is how [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-read-only) dictates it.

Comment: To the best of my understanding a read-only element doesn't prevent programmatic access or updates, only user input. How would you expect a user to update a select-element's value or content natively? Although it's somewhat interesting to read that "*The attribute is not supported or relevant to `<select>` or input types that are already not mutable*" (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly).

Comment: It's closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375526/why-is-read-only-css-pseudo-class-being-applied-on-this-checkbox), though that one is about checkboxes instead of select-elements.

Comment: IOW the semantics are "can an user actually edit the value(s) here"; a [combo box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box) (which can be emulated with `<input>` + `<datalist>`) would not be `:read-only`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### What conditions should be matched for a `<select>` to get the `:read-only` pseudo element?

Quoting [*The Mutability Pseudo-classes* docs](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/selectors/#rw-pseudos):

> An element matches `:read-write` if it is **user-alterable**, as defined by the document language. **Otherwise**, it is `:read-only`.

Quoting the `:read-only` [HTML Specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/):

> The `:read-write` [pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#pseudo-class) must match any element falling into one of the following categories, which for the purposes of Selectors are thus considered user-alterable: [[SELECTORS]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#refsSELECTORS)
>
> - <sup>`<input>` elements to which the readonly attribute applies, and that are mutable (i.e. that do not have the readonly attribute specified and that are not disabled)</sup>
> - <sup>`<textarea>` elements that do not have a readonly attribute, and that are not disabled</sup>
> - **Elements that are [editing hosts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#editing-host) or [editable](https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#editable) and are neither `<input>` elements nor `<textarea>` elements**
>
> The :read-only [pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#pseudo-class) must match all other HTML elements.

##### So for a `<select>` to get the `read-only` attribute, *it must not be*

- User-alterable
- An editing host
- Editable

---

Addressing these criteria one by one

##### - User-alterable

<sup>*Looking for a quote to back this*</sup>

##### - An editing host

Quoting the [*whatwh* editing host definition specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#editing-host):

> An editing host is either an [HTML element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#html-elements) with its [`contenteditable`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-contenteditable) attribute in the true state or plaintext-only state, or a [child](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-child) [HTML element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#html-elements) of a [Document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#document) whose [design mode enabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#design-mode-enabled) is true.

Clearly, the `<select>` does not match these criteria

##### - Editable

Again, quoting the [relevant common definitions specs](https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#editable):

> Something is editable if it is a [node](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node); it is not an [editing host](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#editing-host); it does not have a `contenteditable` attribute set to the false state; its [parent](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-parent) is an [`editing host`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#editing-host) or [editable](https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#editable); and either it is an [HTML element](https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#html-element), or it is an `svg` or `math` element, or it is not an Element and its parent is an [HTML element](https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#html-element).

A `<select>` is of type `HTMLElement`, so without the `contenteditable` attribute, it's not editable